# How to adapt a loop's structure to a user's preference?

Tags: vba, loops, excel

I'm using a loop to fill a collection. There are a few properties for each item of the collection, but some of these properties are optional. The user is prompted to choose which properties will be copied to the collection. Is it possible to omit the code for the optional properties if the user has chosen to ignore them?

```
Sub fillcoll()
    Dim coll as Collection
    Set coll = New Collection
    Dim NewItem as Class1

    For each r in Selection.Rows
        Set NewItem = New Class1

        If Userform1.Checkbox1.Value = True then
            NewItem.Property1 = somearray1(r.Row)
        End If

        If Userform1.Checkbox2.Value = True then
            NewItem.Property2 = somearray2(r.Row)
        End If

        If Userform1.Checkbox3.Value = True then
            NewItem.Property3 = somearray3(r.Row)
        End If

    Next r
End Sub
```

With this code, the Checkboxes' values are read at each iteration. I fear that this may slow down the program's execution unnecessarily. The checkboxes could be read once and the loop's contents would adapt to the checkboxes' values. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "I fear that this may slow down the program's execution unnecessarily." Fear or know? Have you checked yourself before asking? Don't optimize unless you know you have to optimize. If you don't know, then find out.

Comment: If you have a background process that involves 10,000 interations, saving a micro seconds or two per iteration is worthwhile.  But you have a user who must read the screen, make decisions, move their fingers, press keys and click the mouse.  The user will never notice any time saved.

Comment: I agree with JCM and Tony here. You might just be worrying about something which might not be even there. BTW what does somearray1,2,3 do? Also you might want to read the range in an array and then loop through it rather than looping the rows itself. That would also increase the speed of the loop.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I just wanted to know if there was a programming technique I didn't know about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the checkboxes at the beginning,out of the loop, and assign their values to three booleans or an array of booleans. then you just read from the boolean variables every time.

this will improve performance since you do not need to access any object variable, but just a boolean that lays inside your class/object.

Comment: Thanks. But is it possible to even avoid reading from a variable? The three IFs in my code seem unnecessary.

Comment: if you want to avoid code repetition it's much better to use booleans. accessing a boolean is a lot fast anyway. i think you can access a boolean more than few Billions times per second

Comment: The repeated references to a cell `(r.Row)` will also slow down the code, possibly more than checking the check boxes